# Ruby-Double quotes are missing when running shell script

Tags: ruby, json, shell

I have some json created from some data I send out and when I pass the json stored in a variable to another script ( created in python) I noticed that json elements are no longer double quotes

```
json = @report.resultReportToJSON(result_type, result, unit)
puts "#{json}"
`"python ./post_request.py  --json '#{json}'"`
```

My output is like this. From the puts it is :

```
{"test_name":"Launch","requester":"foo","device_serial":"1234"}
```

and the command that gets executed ( we have some logging that outputs the command) is

```
post_request.py --relative_path '/api/benchmark/' --json '{test_name:Launch,requester:foo,device_serial:1234}'
```

You can noticed the double quotes are gone

Comment: this looks suspicious: ```"python ./post_request.py  --json '#{json}'"``` -- why is the entire command in double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about, instead of backticks, use `system`:

```
system "python", "./post_request.py", "--json", json
```

Since backtick'ed commands are executed by /bin/sh, the double quotes are getting gobbled up by the shell. Using `system` relieves you from playing guessing games with quotes:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> json = '{"test_name":"Launch","requester":"foo","device_serial":"1234"}'
=> "{\"test_name\":\"Launch\",\"requester\":\"foo\",\"device_serial\":\"1234\"}"
irb(main):002:0> puts `echo #{json}`
test_name:Launch requester:foo device_serial:1234
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> puts `echo "#{json}"`
{test_name:Launch,requester:foo,device_serial:1234}
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> puts `echo '#{json}'`
{"test_name":"Launch","requester":"foo","device_serial":"1234"}
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> system "echo", json
{"test_name":"Launch","requester":"foo","device_serial":"1234"}
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
require 'json'
`"python ./post_request.py  --json '#{json.to_json}'"`
```

This may help to ensure the object is serialized with escaped quotes when translated to a system command.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.